# Azure Service Bus | Enable Session | Session does not receive

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a requirement to process the same set of messages together and for this, I was trying Azure Service Bus Sessions Enabled feature. To test this, I created a very simple application, a message is submitted successfully in a queue, however, while trying to receive the message in "ReceiveSessionMessage" function, a message session is not returned and the program exits after this line.

I am not able to figure out the exact root cause, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

> [var messageSession = await
> sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync();]

**Program**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSendReceiveMessagesAzure
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionString = "";
        static string queueName = "demosessionqueue";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Service Bus Session! enable feature");
            SendMessage();
            Console.WriteLine("Message Pushed");
            ReceiveSessionMessage();
        }

        private static void SendMessage()
        {
            QueueClient queueClilent = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            string msgJson = "{PizzaType:Veggie,SessionID:SessionId0101}";
            Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgJson))
            {
                SessionId = "SessionId0101"
            };
            Console.WriteLine(msgJson);
            queueClilent.SendAsync(message).Wait();
        }

        private static async Task ReceiveSessionMessage()
        {
            var sessionClient = new SessionClient(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            Console.WriteLine("Accepting a message session...");
            try
            {
                var messageSession = await sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Message.SessionID={messageSession.SessionId}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

[image]

Comment: Please see the sample code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample03_SendReceiveSessions.md.

Comment: Thanks! @GauravMantri for your response. I tried the one which you shared and called it from Program and it resulted in the same issue. Later I found its an issue with the concepts of async and await, which I have explained in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the declaration of

> static void Main(string[] args) , and the calling method "ReceiveSessionMessage()" in it. The correct way of calling this function from the Program.cs was

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Message Session Handler..");
        await MessageSessionReceiver();
    }
```

"ReceiveSessionMessage" function was an async function and the calling function did not have the **await** keyword mentioned due to which the program exited. After changing the syntax to add await, it worked.